# Find a logical formula which is a tautology if and only if this relation is a function

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Assume $A = \{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $B = \{b_1,...,b_k\}$ are finite sets and $P = \{p_{i,j} | 1\leq i \leq n, 1\leq j \leq k\}$ a set of logical variables. Every truth assignment $b$ of $P$ induces a relation $R_b\subset A\times B$ with:

$$(a_i,b_j)\in R_b \Leftrightarrow b(p_{i,j})=1$$

Find a logical formula $\varphi$ so that:

$\hat{b}(\varphi)=1 \Leftrightarrow R_b$ is a function.

**My solution:**

$R_b$ is a function means that: $\quad \forall a \exists b: aR_bb$

My idea was to make this problem more accessible by writing the variables $p_{i,j}$ in a matrix form. And realizing that exactly one of every row has to be picked, i.e. I need all formulas which are true when only one of every row is true and connect and construct the disjunction of them. (rows are correlating to the first index variable $i$):

$J:=\{1,...,n\}$
$m:=max\{n,k\}$

$\varphi :=\bigvee\limits_{j\in J^m}(\bigwedge\limits_{i\in J}(p_{i,j_i}\land \bigwedge\limits_{k\in J\setminus \{i\}}\lnot p_{k,j_k}))$

My problem is that I don't really know how to prove my result and I also think there is a simpler more elegant solution to this. Can someone help me with another approach to this? I probably have stared to long at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $R_b$ is a function $\Leftrightarrow \forall a\in A,\exists!b\in B:aR_b b\ $. 
($\exists!$ means "these exists a unique")

Now, to cover "$\forall a$", we need $\bigwedge$ along all $i\in\{0,1,...,n\}$. So, $\varphi=\bigwedge_{i=1}^n ...$

Then, to cover the *"there exist a unique $b$ such that..."* part, we have $k$ disjunctions:

*"$p_{i,1}$ is true and all other $p_{i, m}, m\neq 1$ are false"*, OR

*"$p_{i,2}$ is true and all other $p_{i, m}, m\neq 2$ are false"*, OR

..., OR

*"$p_{i,k}$ is true and all other $p_{i, m}, m\neq k$ are false."*

Formally, the "there exist a unique $b$ such that..." part would be:
$\bigvee_{j=1}^k(p_{i,j}\wedge\bigwedge_{m\in \{1,..,k\}\setminus j} \neg p_{i,m}).$

Combining, we get the final formula:
$$\varphi=\bigwedge_{i=1}^n\bigvee_{j=1}^k(p_{i,j}\wedge\bigwedge_{m\in \{1,..,k\}\setminus j} \neg p_{i,m}).$$